# SqlServer - accessing data on other database on the same server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm creating a trigger that should create or delete data on a table on another database than my own. If the database is running on a different server, I can add a linked server, and be able to access it that way. 
But what if both databases are running on the same sql server, but with different usernames and passwords? How can I give Db1.user1 access to Db2? I guess one solution is to add user1 to Db2, but can I also "tell" sql server that when Db1.user1 is trying to access Db2, please use user2?
I am running Ms SqlServer 2008 r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use linked server connection not only to connect to a remote server but also to link to another database on the same server ... and specify credentials if needed ...

Comment: This works (if you know how to set it up), but I believe that it is technically "not supported".

Comment: not supported for what reason? never heard of anything like that ... I currently use this without any problems